# How to avoid overlapping of elements in html

Tags: html, css

my homepage's master page has spaces at the left and right side and I want to place in these spaces some pictures. But when I ever scale down my browser it overlaps with the homepage content itself. As far as see, the absolute positioning is here not the solution (also a table). How can I solve this problem? With relative positioning?

```
<style type="text/css">
   #cover { position: absolute;
   height: 385px; width: 282px;    
   left: 50px; top: 250px; }    
</style>

<div id="cover">
 <a href="..." title="..."><img align="right" src="xxx.png" title="..." width="282" height="385"/>  
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: change width and height into Percentage (%) and also left and right values.

Comment: Please post a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Trying giving the body tag a position: relative property. Also it helps if you post a fiddle/plnkr/codepen

Comment: no one will help you unless you post your entire code in fiddle